# Failing to Run Migrations At AWS RDS Database From Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: node.js, postgresql, gitlab, amazon-rds, knex.js

I made a CI/CD pipeline to automatizate the deploy into the AWS Lambda and RDS. Also, create migrations using [Knex Migrations](https://knexjs.org), with NodeJS, to update this database. So, one of the tasks in the CI/CI pipeline is to run the migrations.

The migrations works perfectly running from my computer and the CI/CD is running all the other tasks, even to update the function at AWS Lambda.

The problem is the migration can't connect to the RDS, so it fails. I think it's related to the inboud IP address whitelist (my computer IP is whitelisted), but I don't know what gitlab IP to use in this case. Also tried this [High Availability tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/aws/) with Gitlab, but didn't work (I did the exact tutorial, but fails in the part I need to create a subnet for the database).

How to make this pipeline to run properly and migrate the database?

[EDIT]
This is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
image: node:8.10

stages:
  - migrate

before_script:
    - npm install -g knex
    - npm install -g pg

migrate:
  stage: migrate
  only: 
    - master
  script:
    - cd ./api && knex migrate:latest --env production
  environment: production
```

Answer (score -1):

Is not a definitive solution, but everything works when I set a inbound IP with `0.0.0.0/0`.